# Detect when device power on with React native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Did anyone get an idea on how to detect when a device powers on in React Native?
Basically, I am trying to perform some operations when the phone power on but can't find any existing examples online. I would appreciate any help on how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a react-native-autostart packets. like [this one](https://github.com/qwilmessenger/react-native-autostart).
It asks the user to enable the phone to automatically start the app on power on.
Might not fully answer your demand, but it's a user-friendly ways to do it, this way they'll know what's happening.